# Xamarin.Forms vertical text alignment not working for Labels with FormattedText with several Spans in it that have different font sizes

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label

The issue is also described here 
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4239 
 
I need a way to make a label with several spans, some of those spans should have smaller FontSize and the letters in those spans should be vertically aligned to the top of the line. 
 
Basically I need to have small letters at the top of the line inside a label.

Maybe I should make a custom renderer?
If so - could you please provide me with some sample about how to do that?
Anything will do, I just need a way to implement that.

Now my code looks somewhat similar to this:

```
<Label
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
    FontSize="{Binding ArabicFontSize}"
    Margin="0"
    TextColor="{Binding GetLineTextColor}"
>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{Binding ArabicText1}" TextColor="Black"/>
            <Span Text="{Binding ArabicRedSign1}" TextColor="Red" FontSize="{Binding ArabicFontSizeHalved}" />
            <Span Text="{Binding ArabicGreenSign1}" TextColor="Green" FontSize="{Binding ArabicFontSizeHalved}"/>

            <Span Text="{Binding ArabicText2}" TextColor="Black"/>
            <Span Text="{Binding ArabicRedSign2}" TextColor="Red" FontSize="{Binding ArabicFontSizeHalved}"/>
            <Span Text="{Binding ArabicGreenSign2}" TextColor="Green" FontSize="{Binding ArabicFontSizeHalved}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
```

Comment: By my searching, I find **Label.YAlign** Property may have this effect, but I try it in my code, and don't find any effect temporarily, so I will continue to looking.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been through complications customizing `Span` elements. However, the [Label.Span API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.span?view=xamarin-forms) doesn't include properties to change text alignment on each `Span` block.

For this scenario, you can use a `<StackLayout>` horizontally oriented and a set of `Label` elements to simulate a paragraph with different vertical text alignments.

This is a XAML example:

```
<StackLayout
    BackgroundColor="Red"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    Spacing="0">
    <Label
        Text="Base"
        TextColor="White"
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label
            Text="upper text"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="Micro"
            VerticalOptions="Start"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And this is the generated UI:

[image]

Changing the value of the alignment properties for each `Label` element would help you to adjust the layout to fit your needs.

You can go further and create a custom control in order to make this component reusable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve your requirements with below code

```
                   <Label HorizontalOptions="End"  x:Name="lblRegister">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="New User?" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Span Text="SIGN UP" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
```

[image]